# Retrieve recompose local dispatch function from withReducer in withHandlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I have a component which is already connected to the `redux` store and has the `dispatch` injected to it. I am trying to update the local state of the component using `withReducer` and `withHandlers` like this:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_ACTIVE_TAB':
      console.log('recieved action', action)
      const { activeTab } = action
      return activeTab
    default:
     return state
  }
```

}

```
const initialState = 'actions'

const handlers = withHandlers({
  onTabClick: props => (e, { name }) => {
    const { dispatchLocal } = props
    dispatchLocal({
      type: 'SET_ACTIVE_TAB',
      activeTab: name
    })
  }
})

const enhancer = withReducer('activeTab', 'dispatchLocal', reducer, initialState)
```

I find that when I `compose`:

```
compose(handlers, enhancer)(LayerListItem)
```

The `dispatchLocal` prop is not defined within the `handler`. What is the best way of creating and binding action creators with `recompose` to update the application state.

Answer (score 0):

You should move `withReducer` to the right of `withHandlers`:

```
compose(
  withReducer(...),
  withHandlers(...)
)
```

In this way, `withReducer` will create the dispatch function first and append it to `props`, then `withHandlers` can consume it.